# Asp.net core 502.5 - Process Failure error when deployed - logging issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

I need some help getting logging working on my asp.net core, mvc version 2.1 site.  I've been able to get the site to write errors to the Event log successfully, but only to the Application/Application EventLog/Source.  I was hoping to set the Source to "MySite", so I can easily filter the logs.

Here's my Program.cs code that produces the 502.5 error when deployed:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            var eventLogSettings = new EventLogSettings();
            eventLogSettings.SourceName = "MySite";

            logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings);
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
        })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

When I deploy the site, and go to the /home/index page, I get the 502.5 error and see the following error logged in the Event viewer:

Application: dotnet.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.6.27019.6
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It was right there in the exception, dang it.
The CoreCLR was bombing out when it tried to verify the source, which didn't exist on the server.
I created the source by running the following command in powershell as administrator:
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource(“MySite”, “Application”)

After that the site worked fine and the errors from it have the source "MySite".